# Windows Phone 8.0 ListBox Out Of Memory Extension

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, out-of-memory

Sorry for my english.
I'am execute next code:
in XAML
...

```
<Button Content="Add More" Width="160"  Click="Button_Click_2"/>  
<ListBox x:Name="list"/>
```

...

in CS
...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
             list.Items.Add(new Image { Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("http://pravda-team.ru/eng/image/photo/4/7/4/73474.jpeg") } });
            }
```

...

This code working, but if I click on the button a few times, there is an exception "Out Of Memory Extension"
I tried to use Garbage Collector and AutoCaching, but the error persists.
I catch this extension on the next screen shot:
[image]

Comment: What phone do you use for testing? I tried this on my Lumia 730. Tapped the button hundreds of times and haven't noticed error like this. Images (one image but many times) are loaded everything works fast and smooth.

Comment: I'am testing on Lumia 620. For the simplified catch the exception, you must add the following code in the file App.cs:
 private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message.ToString());
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
               
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may happen when your `ListBox` is inside another `ScrollViewer` or in `StackPanel`. Normally `ListBox` has its own `ScrollViewer`, it renders only items that are currently visible. But if you place the `ListBox` inside `ScrollViewer`, then the whole `ListBox` must be rendered and you're going to reach memory exception.

This layout will cause problems:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Button Content="add more"
            Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Row="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But this one will work fine, fast and smooth:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="add more"
            Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want your `ListBox` to scroll properly, its size must be limited. You can do it by placing it inside `Grid` layout, but setting hard-coded height will work too. `ListBox` must know the size of its viewport to optimize items rendering.